# Regular expression for prefix numeric values and a specific range of letters from the alphabet

Tags: regex, string, expression, string-matching

I need a regular expression that will allow me to enter a specific set of characters.

The regular expression should not allow me to enter numeric values only unless the numeric value entered is prefix with '9999'.

It should also not allow me to enter any string of data if it contains any letter pass "F" from the alphabet.

And lastly, the length of the value entered should not exceed 12 characters/digits

Is the above possible?

I have a regular expression that will take care of the length and numeric values only but I need assistance with the prefix and letters pass "F".

```
 ^(?![0-9]*$)[a-zA-Z0-9]{12}$
```

Valid Samples:

```
 3847a654b321
 3899c654b876
 999946578432
 999975620983
```

Invalid Samples:

```
 874k459m8723
 546p34s85734
 543216789012
 243567890218
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Why is 3847a654b321 valid? It's not prefixed with 9999?

Comment: Because is not a numeric value only and it the two letters are between a-f. The prefix only applies when the value is numeric only.

Comment: Thank you. That took care of the prefix & numeric values only but it removed the 12 character validation. I'm able to enter values greater than 12 characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Brief

Based on the following information:

- All digits, must begin with `9999` or digits and characters in the `a-f` range only
- Max length of 12 characters

### Code

This is the regex you're looking for:

[See this regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/nLsDOt/1)

```
^(?:9{4}\d{8}|(?=.*[a-f].*)[\da-f]{12})$
```

### Explanation

- Assert position at start of line/string
- Match 4 `9`s followed by 8 of any digit **OR** ensure there is a character in the `a-f` range ahead and ensure it's made up of 12 of any digit or character in the `a-f` range
- Assert position at end of line/string

Answer (score 0):

Split the regex in two cases:

```
^(9999[0-9]{8})|((?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-fA-F])([a-fA-F0-9]{12}))$
 \------------/ \------------------------------------------/
       1                              2
```

1. Numeric values that start with 9999
2. Values that contain at least one character between `A` and `F` and numbers